# Exposed an inner control of a frame as property, but changes aren't registered. What did I forget to register?

Tags: delphi, frame

I registered a frame of mine as component. After that I exposed an inner control property (`TListView.Columns`, in this case).

But changes are not stored in the dfm, causing the program to ignore whatever columns I created in design time.

I even exposed the entire list-view. But still nothing is saved in the dfm.

```
  TFme_CustomAssociatedFiles = class(TFrame)
    ...
    Lsv_Files: TListView;
  ...
  published
    property InternalListView: TListview read Lsv_Files;
    ...
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I thought a little, I remembered an component called `TLabeledEdit`. I compared it's source with my source and the result is what's needed to do is marking the control/component exposed as sub-component calling `TComponent.SetSubComponent()`.

So, in the constructor of the frame I had to include:

```
constructor TFme_CustomAssociatedFiles.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  ...
  Lsv_Files.SetSubComponent(true);
  ...
end;
```

And all worked like a charm.